# How to Iterate through nodes and skip duplicate nodes with same value using a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have a xml like,

```
        <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>xxx</SHORT-NAME>
          <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">ABC/DEF/123</TYPE-TREF>
        </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>yyy</SHORT-NAME>
          <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">LMN/OPQ/123</TYPE-TREF>
        </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>mmm</SHORT-NAME>
          <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">XYZ/GHY/456</TYPE-TREF>
        </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>nnn</SHORT-NAME>
          <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">AJK/UTL/456</TYPE-TREF>
        </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
```

My xslt,

```
    <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string"
            select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:for-each select="select="//DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE/ea:TYPE-TREF[@TYPE='DESIGN-FUNCTION-TYPE']">
      <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="current()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="taskName" select="../ea:SHORT-NAME"/>

         <xsl:variable name="Var7">    
         <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
         <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$myVar" />
         <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'/'" />
         </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:variable>

         <varoutput> 
         <xsl:value-of select="$Var7"/>
         </varoutput>

</xsl:for-each>
```

My intention here is to iterate all the 'DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE' elements and display the sub-string of 'TYPE-TREF' value, but if a sub-string of 'TYPE-TREF' value has already been read..i must skip that element.

Expected output,

```
123
456
```

And Not,

```
123
123
456
456
```

In general I should consider only the first occurrence and skip the rest.

Comment: You've tagged this XSLT-1.0, but in a previous question you commented you are using Saxon 9.8HE which supports XSLT 3.0? Can you confirm which processor you are actually using, as it will be much easier to solve this in XSLT 3.0. Thanks!

Comment: I will be using XSLT-1.0 (xalan) @TimC . I use saxon online editor to see quick outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, without relying on processor-specific extensions, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE" use="substring-after(substring-after(TYPE-TREF, '/'), '/')"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE[count(. | key('k1', substring-after(substring-after(TYPE-TREF, '/'), '/'))[1]) = 1]">
            <varoutput> 
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(TYPE-TREF, '/'), '/')" />
            </varoutput> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9s

This is of course assuming that the value you're after is always the third "token" in `TYPE-TREF`. Otherwise you would have to do something similar to your attempt:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT node-set() function**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="value" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <!-- EXTRACT VALUES -->
    <xsl:variable name="values">
        <xsl:for-each select="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">
            <value> 
                 <xsl:call-template name="last-token">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="TYPE-TREF"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </value> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($values)/value[count(. | key('k1', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <varoutput> 
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </varoutput> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="last-token">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="last-token">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9s/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Xalan you should have access to the EXSLT `str:split` function (http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltStrings.html#split(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" exclude-result-prefixes="str" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="group" match="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE/TYPE-TREF"
        use="str:split(., '/')[last()]"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:for-each select="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE/TYPE-TREF[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', str:split(., '/')[last()])[1])]">
            <varoutput>
                <xsl:value-of select="str:split(., '/')[last()]"/>
            </varoutput>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>xxx</SHORT-NAME>
        <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">ABC/DEF/123</TYPE-TREF>
    </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
    <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>yyy</SHORT-NAME>
        <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">LMN/OPQ/123</TYPE-TREF>
    </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
    <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>mmm</SHORT-NAME>
        <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">XYZ/GHY/456</TYPE-TREF>
    </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
    <DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>nnn</SHORT-NAME>
        <TYPE-TREF TYPE="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE">AJK/UTL/456</TYPE-TREF>
    </DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE>
</Root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><varoutput>123</varoutput><varoutput>456</varoutput>
```

with Xalan Java and Xalan Java XSLTC.

Or, as suggested in a comment, if you simply want to find the distinct values you can use `set:distinct` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl str set"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:variable name="split-values">
            <xsl:for-each select="DESIGN-FUNCTION-PROTOTYPE/TYPE-TREF">
                <xsl:copy-of select="str:split(., '/')[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>        
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="set:distinct(exsl:node-set($split-values)/node())"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Xalan also supports `set:distinct()`, so you don't need to use Muenchian grouping.